# how to differentiate between programmatically scrolling list view and manually doing so?

Tags: android, android-listview

I need to differentiate between programmatically scrolling a list view and manually scrolling a list view. I am not quite sure how to do it. Any idea ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I guess a way would be to do something like add onscrollchanged listener and onTouch listener to the listview. And keep a boolean like fromUser.

In the onTouch listener you can set the flag to true on MotionEvent.ActionDown. When the MotionEvent is ActionUp you can set the flag to false.

So whenever the scroll listener is fired you can check the flag and see whether its from the user or not.